# MySQL query with SUM, WHERE, LIKE, and GROUP BY eventually to be a rails 4 activerecord search

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Okay, I have a query that I know works on a single table.

```
SELECT model, SUM(quantity)
FROM orders
WHERE status IN ('Completed','Shipped','Cart Submitted')
AND YEAR(needby) = '2015'
GROUP BY model
```

That query provides me with good data; however, when I update it to try and filter some more to the following:

```
SELECT model, SUM(quantity)
FROM orders
WHERE status IN ('Completed','Shipped','Cart Submitted')
AND YEAR(needby) = '2015'
AND projectid LIKE 'ABC'
GROUP BY model
```

It no longer returns anything(yes I have projectids that are LIKE ABC).  I tried adding projectid to the select, but that doesn't help.

I also tried using SELECT (CASE WHEN projectid LIKE 'ABC' THEN projectid END), model, SUM(quantity), but that just added an empty column and still returned the same stuff from the first search.

I also have to be able to translate this to a rails activerecord search eventually, so extremely complex SQL may not work well.  I always try and get my data working in SQL before I try and move it over to my rails app. Eventually this will be a series of queries that will allow me to use chartkick and display the data graphically.

Comment: Are you sure you want `LIKE 'ABC'` ? Not `LIKE 'ABC%'` or `LIKE '%ABC%'` ? Cause  LIKE without wildcard is equivalent to an `='ABC'`

Comment: hmm, maybe.  Let me give that a try.  I thought I tried a WC in the front, but looking at my projectid field it would need to be at the back.

Comment: Raph, please repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `LIKE 'ABC'` (without a wild card), this is just as if you do `='ABC'`

So you may rather want something like

```
LIKE 'ABC%'
```

or

```
LIKE '%ABC'
```

or

```
LIKE '%ABC%'
```